# MS Management studio import wizard External table is not in the expected format. Excel (XLSX)

Tags: excel

I am using the SQL managment studio to run the import wizard to get data from excel file (XlSX). I get the following error:
External table is not in the expected format. (Microsoft Office Access Database Engine)

The excel file is not password protected and it was created in office 2003 (95% sure)

I have read articles suggesting missing drivers. I have installed all the following:
Microsoft Office version    Download
2016    Microsoft Access 2016 Runtime
2013    Microsoft Access 2013 Runtime
2010    Microsoft Access 2010 Runtime
2007    2007 Office System Driver: Data Connectivity Components

Nothing of these worked for me. However; if I open the excel file, click save, close it and then import it using the wizard it works.

The problem is that I would like to automate this process. So opening 200 files, save them, and then close them is not an option.

My specs:
windows 10, 
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 12.0.4459.0
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools 12.0.4459.0
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC) 10.0.14393.0
Microsoft MSXML  3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer 9.11.14393.0
Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0.30319.42000
Operating System 6.3.14393

The only thing that I found starnge here is the following:
Microsoft MSXML  3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0. 
Is this the correct value. If not, how do I update it?

This is my second day looking for a solution to this problem with no luck. If anyone could help.

Comment: Why not automate the open-save-close process across all files in a directory? VBA from within Excel would allow you to do that.

Comment: Hello Bennett. Thanks for the suggestion. This would not work as the files are coming from different people, they upload it to us.